# Passing Dynamic Date Variable in Big Query| Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I'm trying to run this bigQuery [in python]:

```
  start_date= "2022-03-08"
  end_date = "2022-05-03"
  query = f"""
    SELECT SUM(CostInBillingCurrency) as cost,EXTRACT(MONTH from date) as MONTH, SubscriptionId, SubscriptionName
    FROM `table_name`
    WHERE
    Date BETWEEN TIMESTAMP({start_date})
    AND TIMESTAMP({end_date})
    GROUP BY
    SubscriptionId, SubscriptionName,MONTH """
```

this is the error I'm getting:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 No matching signature for function TIMESTAMP for argument types: INT64. Supported signatures: TIMESTAMP(STRING, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(DATE, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(DATETIME, [STRING]); TIMESTAMP(TIMESTAMP) at [5:18]
```

If I hardcode the date as:

```
  Date BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("2022-06-01")
  AND TIMESTAMP("2022-06-30")
```

it works fine. so the query is right.

please help in figuring out how to pass date dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add quotes. If you do `result = f'TIMESTAMP({start_date})'`it renders to `TIMESTAMP(2022-06-01)`. So change it to `result = f'TIMESTAMP("{start_date}")` or `result = f"TIMESTAMP('{start_date}')"` and you should be good.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the the variable is just putting values in the query, but query is expecting the string, you update your query as follows

```
query = f"""
SELECT SUM(CostInBillingCurrency) as cost,EXTRACT(MONTH from date) as MONTH, SubscriptionId, SubscriptionName
FROM `table_name`
WHERE
Date BETWEEN TIMESTAMP("{start_date}")
AND TIMESTAMP("{end_date}")
GROUP BY
SubscriptionId, SubscriptionName,MONTH """
```